# JPA composite primary key referencing objects; JSF

Tags: jsf, jpa, composite-primary-key

as the heading implies, I've got a composite primary key that should reference two objects, in order to be able to acces those in JSF lateron.

Class should look like this...:

```
    @Entity
    public class Timetable {
        public static final String findAll = "Timetable.findAll";

        @Id
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "lectureId")
        private Lecture lecture;

        @Id
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "timeslotId")
        private Timeslot timeslot;
```

... so I can later access those objects in JSF like this:

```
#{timetable.timeslot.timeslotId}
```

However glassfish is now caliming about missmatching types since *lecture* and *timeslot* are objects but reference primary key of type Long.

Is there an easy trick to fix this?

For further information I had a look at the following sources:
[http://docs.oracle.com/...](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm#BCGIGBEI)

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: That link merely explains typical `@Embeddable` and `@IdClass` annotations respectively that can be used to form a composite primary key. Those `Lecture` and `Timeslot` composite/complex objects appear to be entities forming a `@ManyToOne` relationship with `Timetable`. How could they then be part of a composite primary key in your RDBMS? You could however, have a separate/usual primary key field (non-composite) in your database table retaining both of these relationships as they are.